# Umbraco Forms - Use Record ID in workflow email

Tags: forms, umbraco, umbraco-contour

I need to have a unique identifier within the Email subject. Is it possible to use the RecordId of the Entry within a workflow email?

I've tried using `{record.id}` within the Message/Subject field and it only returns the value of 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found out that `{record.id}` isn't populated on submission (for obvious reasons). You can't use this within the "When the form is submitted..." workflow. But you can use use it during the "When the form is approved..." workflow.

Comment: BennyC how do you create a workflow for after form is approved?